# How can I set a delegate and a datasource to a UITableViewController's view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is my code as for now, which is wrong. I am not getting the viewDidLoad due to the changing of the view.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.view = tableView;
tableViewController.title = @"test";

tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

What I really need is to change the `tableViewController`'s view's `delegate` and `datasource` to my `self`.
The problem is that I can't do it for some reason.

Something like that would have been great:

```
tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
tableViewController.title = @"test";

tableViewController.view.delegate = self;
tableViewController.view.dataSource = self;
```

But for some reason I can't set `tableViewController`'s view property's delegate nor datasource.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Is TableViewController a UITableViewController?  view is a property on UIViewController which returns a UIView, which does not have a delegate or datasource.  However, UITableViewController has a tableView property for the tableView.  These objects are the same thing, but calling view will cast it to a UIView.  Just use .tableView instead.  Also, you don't want to create and assign a UITableView in this case.  If TableViewController is just a UIViewController subclass like in Brandon's answer, then you will need to create your own tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the class you're trying to use as the datasource has the proper protocols listed and delegate methods implemented.

```
@interface MyNewViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

Then you should be able to do something like.

```
tableViewController.tableView.delegate = self;
tableViewController.tableView.datasource = self;
```